# Facebook IFrame App with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebooker2

I have created an Iframe Facebook appliation with facebook. How do I enforce the user to see the pop up box and request for permissions? For now, when I hit "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/", the application opens up, but the rails app does not know the fbuid.

In my application controller I have

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
include Facebooker2::Rails::Controller
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.

You can see my gist [Facebooker2 for iframe FB app](https://gist.github.com/1275868)